# Assign/echo php file output to a php variable

Tags: php, variables

I'm coding a live search for a lyrics upload form. I've created a small script which I'll be making AJAX calls to. It returns `artist`, `album`, and `song` records. The output JSON will be used in JS.

```
// get_records.php

include_once("connect2db.php");

if (empty($_GET)) {
    $artists = json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($mysqli->query("SELECT artist from `artists`"), MYSQLI_ASSOC));
    echo $artists;
} else {
    if (isset($_GET["artist"])) {
        $artist = test_input($_GET["artist"]);
        if (isset($_GET["album"])) {
            // ...
            echo $songs;
        } else {
            // ...
            echo $albums;
        }
    }
}

$mysqli->close();
```

It's pretty simple. Designed for three cases:

- `get_records.php // returns artists`
- `get_records.php?artist=XXX // returns albums of XXX`
- `get_records.php?artist=XXX&album=YYY // returns songs from the album YYY that belongs to XXX`

In the form page, I want `artists` to be already assinged to a JS variable before any input. I don't want to use AJAX for that. One way I could make it work is like this:

```
<?php
    echo "var artists = ";
    include("get_records.php");
    echo ";";
?>
```

but this just seems wrong. Is there a way to do it like this

```
<?php
    echo "var artists = " . get_output("get_records.php") . ";";
?>
```

you know, get the output of the php file, not it's content?

Comment: How about `echo "var artists = " . file_get_contents("http://localhost/get_records.php") . ";";`?

Comment: @revo Already tried that. This just reads the contents of the file and returns it as a string. Doesn't execute the code inside the file.

Comment: this should work fine as is because you're including it inside a php file, so the output will be the output, not the contents of the php code.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` sends a request to a file hosted on your web server (like how you do that by typing in address bar and hitting enter!) then by that, requested PHP file is being interpreted, compiled and executed and finally, unless your web server is not up and running, you will have the right output .

Comment: @revo `a.php` contents: `<?php
 echo "printing ab.php output = " . file_get_contents("ab.php");
?>` | `ab.php` contents: `<?php
 echo "ab";
?>` | `a.php` output: 
`printing ab.php output = <?php
 echo "ab";
?>`

Comment: You should change it to an URL: `file_get_contents("http://path/to/your/ab.php");`

Comment: Oh, this way it works.

Comment: Yes, file get contents is enough, no need to ob_*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting your code inside a function and then call it from the other scripts as per your need.

Main script:

```
 <?php

// get_records.php

function execute()
{
    // get_records.php

    include_once("connect2db.php");

    if (empty($_GET)) {
        $artists = json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($mysqli->query("SELECT artist from `artists`"), MYSQLI_ASSOC));
        $response = $artists;
    } else {
        if (isset($_GET["artist"])) {
            $artist = test_input($_GET["artist"]);
            if (isset($_GET["album"])) {
                // ...
                $response = $songs;
            } else {
                // ...
                $response = $albums;
            }
        }
    }

    $mysqli->close();

    return $response;
}
```

Ajax Script:

```
<?php
// ajax_script.php

include_once("get_records.php");

echo execute();
```

Form Script

```
<?php

// Form File - form_file.php
include_once("get_records.php");

$content = execute();

$response = "<script> var artists = $content ; </script>";

echo $response;
```